# Serial communication with Python

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, python

I am trying to send integer from my Python program to Arduino MEGA.
If I send 1, the LED should turn on and If  I send 0 the LED should turn off.

I was able to write Python code correctly as I think. I have configure the port and made `serialWrite(val)` function for send data to Arduino only if data is changed.
This not a full program. It has while loop. So, it writes data to Arduino rapidly. I used `serialWrite(val)` function to prevent that.

But, the LED never turns off, if I send 0. It turns on only. What are the problems in my code?

```
import serial as ser

prt = ser.Serial(
port='COM3',
baudrate=9600,
parity=ser.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=ser.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=ser.EIGHTBITS
)

preSerVal=0
#function for send data..data will send only val is changed
def serialWrite(val):
    global preSerVal
    if(not preSerVal == val):
        prt.write(str(val)+'\r\n')
        preSerVal=val
```

This is my Arduino program.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
byte incomingByte;

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
      if (incomingByte == '1') {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    } else if (incomingByte == '0') {
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I write testing program like this.

Python code:

```
import serial as ser
import time

preSerVal=0
prt = ser.Serial(
port='COM3',
baudrate=9600,
parity=ser.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=ser.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=ser.EIGHTBITS
)
def serialWrite(val):
    global preSerVal
    if(not preSerVal == val):
         prt.write(str(val)+'\r\n')
         preSerVal=val

while 1:
   for i in range(0,10):
        serialWrite(0)
   time.sleep(1)
   for i in range(0,10):
        serialWrite(1)
```

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
byte incomingByte;

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
  if (incomingByte == '1') {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  } else if (incomingByte == '0') {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
 }
}
```

This code gives this result.
see the video bellow:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utC4vo8YDVU&list=PLM5AA5oFchgC25da44Q2X900pz0eojSQJ&index=1

**UPDATE 2**

This is a piece of code..it sends 0..i checked it.

```
try:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        houghCenter=(i[0],i[1])
        cv2.circle(src,houghCenter,i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.circle(src,houghCenter,2,(0,255,255),1)
        cv2.circle(drawing,houghCenter,i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.circle(drawing,houghCenter,2,(0,255,255),1)
        #print (houghCenter,"   ",contourCenter)
        dx=math.fabs(houghCenter[0]-contourCenter[0])
        dy =math.fabs(houghCenter[1]-contourCenter[1])
        if (dx>diff and dy>diff):
            serialWrite(0)
        else:
            serialWrite(1)
except Exception:
    serialWrite(0)
```

Comment: You need to post the Python while loop to get a more specific answer. But I'll bet you just aren't sending enough 0s between 1s, for you to notice the LED going off. You did say the while loop is fast. Perhaps you should try slowing it down with `time.sleep(1)` and see if anything changes.

Comment: @TisteAndii .. Thanks... I cant slow down while loop..I have checkered,0 is sent by while loop. That's OK.

Comment: please post the Python while loop. Is the Arduino code working with IDE console ?

Comment: Its huge code with some image processing code...I have update my post..plz see it..

Comment: add `print("0/1")` to see how fast 0 and 1 are sent on PC side. Is the code executed once or in a loop ? What is the expected behaviour and the real bahaviour ?

Comment: I previously added a print command to same place that I call serialWrite(val) function..It was very speed..that's why I used serialWrite(val) function.

Comment: I understand the `serialWrite()` avoids sending twice same data. Then add the `print` after `prt.write` if the 1 and 0 are wery fast you will not have time to see anything blink. If you do not describe the expected and observed behaviour I cannot help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45866/discussion-between-nsiri-and-julien).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a second time.sleep(1). That is why the first loop executes correctly and the the LED flashed faster. Without any time.sleep() at all, the LED is going OFF/ON so fast that you cannot see it happen (may be it's just not so bright as usually).

```
while 1:
   for i in range(0,10):
        serialWrite(0)
   time.sleep(1)
   for i in range(0,10):
        serialWrite(1)
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Its worked now...Thanks..But,How can I apply to my image processing code?

Comment: I have update my post again with piece of image processing code.what is the wrong of that?

Comment: @NSiri Try adding a delay each time you send a 0 or 1. If your algorithm can afford it.